How to Preserve HTML Tags When Updating Content with Angular
am working on an admin panel where the admin can update incorrect questions. The UI is almost complete, but I am facing an issue with preserving HTML tags when updating and submitting data to the database.
The problem is that I am binding the question and options using innerHtml because the response from the database contains HTML tags. When I try to update the content and submit it, the data is stored in the database as plain text, removing all HTML tags. The question may contain images, breaks, spaces, new lines, etc., and if these tags are removed, the alignment gets disturbed.
Here is my HTML component code:
 <h2 mat-dialog-title>Update Question/Options</h2>
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
  <div class="formData">
    <div class="display-container">
      <div class="practicePaperSecondSection">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row practiceExamScreen">
            <div class="practiceQuestionAndSolutionDiv">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <!-- QUESTION BODY -->
                    <div class="card-body question-content QuestionAndSolutionSection">
                      <!-- Question Text & Image -->
                      <div class="text-black">
                        <div class="mt-2">
                          <label>Question:</label>
                          <div *ngIf="!isEditMode" [innerHtml]="editedQuestion" (click)="toggleEditMode()" class='displayText'></div>
                          <textarea *ngIf="isEditMode" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="editedQuestion"></textarea>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="m-3">
                        <div class="option-container">
                          <ul class="optionsList">
                            <li class="cursor-pointer mb-2 text-black" *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index; trackBy: trackByIndex">
                              <div class="d-flex">
                                <div class="label">
                                  <div *ngIf="!isEditMode" [innerHtml]="option" (click)="toggleEditMode()" class='displayText'></div>
                                  <textarea *ngIf="isEditMode" class="form-control ml-3" [(ngModel)]="options[i]"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                
                              </div>
                             
                            </li>
                             <p *ngIf="isEditMode" class="warning-message">Please update only the text content. Ensure to preserve the HTML tags and structure as they are necessary for proper formatting.</p>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <mat-dialog-actions align="end">
                  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
                  <button mat-flat-button color="primary" class="m-3" (click)="submitButton()">Update</button>
                </mat-dialog-actions>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-dialog-content>

these is html component code and here is my .ts component code
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-question',
  templateUrl: './update-question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-question.component.scss']
})
export class UpdateQuestionComponent implements OnInit {

  editedQuestion: string = '';
  options!: string[];
  id: any;
  selectedOption: string = '';
  answerkey: any;
  isEditMode: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<UpdateQuestionComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Getting the data inside the dialog', this.data);
    this.editedQuestion = this.data.question;
    this.options = [...this.data.options];
    this.id = this.data.id;
    this.answerkey = this.data.answerkey;
  }

  submitButton(): void {
    const updatedQuestionData = {
      question_id: this.id,
      question: this.editedQuestion,
      optiona: this.options[0] || '',
      optionb: this.options[1] || '',
      optionc: this.options[2] || '',
      optiond: this.options[3] || '',
      answerkey: this.answerkey || '',
    };
    this.dialogRef.close(updatedQuestionData);
  }

  toggleEditMode(): void {
    this.isEditMode = !this.isEditMode;
  }

  trackByIndex(index: number, obj: any): any {
    return index;
  }
}

Please give me any suggestion so that here I can change only the text and all html tags should remain as it is because some time there will be nested tags as well.

There is a possibility that the tags get stripped by the backend API or database. But from a frontend perspective.
The problem I see is that, you are using a textarea which does not support HTML content. Instead you should use a rich text editor (supports HTML) instead, a good example will be primeng text editor, This will allow you to modify or add HTML and also post the data back to the database.
Primeng Text Editor Website Demo

thanks for your response,
actually there is no use to create the editor for these I think, because I am working on online Exam platform and want to implement the Question and its option Edit option from admin side, and i am gettiing the response from backend in html structure, and i have bind that data to the UI, and now want to update the question or its option then the issue is getting , because in DB for each question and option they have some alignment like for image they have set inline CSS  somewhere space , so if edit then the alignment is getting disturbed

@VishalLengare Then you need to store only data as an array or object in the data base and use angular to render the HTML using ngFor! storing html in the database seems unnecessary!
